# How to add more than one dependency module in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

Hi I am new to angularjs, I want to add more than one dependency module in the app.

Here is my code:

```
var NBModule = angular.module('NBModule', ['ui.router','ngDraggable']);
```

I even tried

```
var NBModule = angular.module('NBModule', ['ui.router'],['ngDraggable']);
```

and finally

```
var NBModule = angular.module('NBModule', ['ui.router']);
angular.injector(NBModule, ['ngDraggable']);
```

i am getting this error:

> [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=undefined&p1=Error%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.5%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A146)

Comment: If you click the error, does it take you to a help page? Are you loading the extra modules in the head section?

Answer (score 6):

The first option you tried is the correct one:

```
var NBModule = angular.module('NBModule', ['ui.router','ngDraggable']);
```

I'm guessing the problem is that you didn't add the script tag in the html.

you need to add:

```
<script src="path/to/uiRouter.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/draggable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the script tags of these dependencies in your HTML like this:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="ui.router.js"></script>
<script src="ng-draggable.js"></script>
```

If that don't work, then `ui-router` might be depending on `ng-draggable` might be